# how to get the count , same values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i want to take the count like same values in table,let say example in my table `Accomodation` is two time are there so,Accomodation count should come 2 and remaining count is 1

> getting_fecilities

```
fid      eventId           fecilityName

 1          5                 Accomodation
 2          5                 Breakfast
 3          5                 Lunch
 4          5                 Dinner
 5          6                 Food(VEG)
 6          5                 Parking
 7          5                 Accomodation
```

> MYSQL

```
SELECT `fecilityName`,COUNT(*) AS count FROM getting_fecilities WHERE eventId=5 group by `fecilityName`
```

> MY Result

```
fecilityName  count

Accomdation    1
Accomdation    1
Breakfast      1
Dinner         1
Lunch          1
Parking        1
```

> My Expected results

```
fecilityName  count

Accomdation    2
Breakfast      1
Dinner         1
Lunch          1
Parking        1
```

Comment: You query is correct check again

Comment: The result that you have posted here is the result of an ungrouped query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is giving the Expected Result.
Have a look at it at the below link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba6457/4

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT `fecilityName`, COUNT(fecilityName) AS count 
    FROM getting_fecilities WHERE eventId = 5 
    group by `fecilityName`;
```